# I see gem in "gem list" but have "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby

I am on Ubuntu10

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

then download sources of rubygem 1.3.7 and install it

```
sudo ruby setup.rb
```

then, for example, install sinatra

```
sudo gem install sinatra
```

Finally open irb and type

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
```

and get error

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- sinatra
    from (irb):2:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In what context and can you quote the errors?  Try reinstalling and passing verbose to see what is going on.

Comment: This question was highlighted in a text book I am currently using (http://beta.saasbook.info/).  Be prepared to get the "popular question" badge soon.

Comment: Came here after reading Engineering Long Lasting Software (SaaS book)

Comment: @J.Hendrix : here for the same reason. Maybe _now_ is when this question _really_ takes off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly this problem. The problem is that gem and ruby disagree about where the gems live. Compare these:

```
ruby -e "puts Gem.path"

gem env

gem which sinatra
```

If you're like my setup, you'll notice that there's an entry in gem env's paths that isn't in Gem.path, and that's exactly where sinatra will claim to be. In my case, I had to add

```
export GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

to my .profile. Then everyone was happy.

Answer (score 3):

Execute

```
sudo gem install sinatra --verbose
```

and note the path where the gem is getting installed.

Then try this in irb

```
puts $LOAD_PATH
```

and make sure that gem is installed in one of the directories in `$LOAD_PATH`

And ideally just start using http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: +1 I think it's easier to adjust the set of directories in the load path (as in my answer), but clearly this will work too.

Answer (score 2):

I usually hit this error when I forget:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

It'd be helpful if you provided the actual code sample, though, what gem you want to require, and what Ruby version you're using if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: as of 1.9 you don't need to require rubygems

Comment: @Isaac Cambron - that's true, which is why I asked for more details. The OP has since provided them. The answer clearly isn't relevant to this particular user at this point, but I'll leave it up for reference :)

Answer (score 1):

This was before here on SO quite a few times. Problem is that you probably have two versions of ruby. The one is installing the gem and the other one is trying to use it. Do this in terminal:

```
$ which -a ruby
```

Or this:

```
$ which -a gem
```

to see if you have more than one version of ruby/gem installed. If so - remove one version (via `$ rm` or package manager of your system).

Comment: i have one ruby and one gem :)

Answer (score 0):

I use ruby gems 1.8.7 for a project. I was getting the same error. Use the line `require 'rubygems'`. It must always be the first require statement, otherwise you can get an error. In my code, I had

```
require 'watir'
require 'rubygems'
# more code
```

I got the error - in `require': no such file to load -- watir (LoadError). 
When I put rubygems first, the error went away and everything worked. I don't know 
why this happens.

Btw, I tried user24359 answer and it did not help me.

```
C:\code>ruby -e "puts Gem.path"
-e:1: uninitialized constant Gem (NameError)
```