# where does ruby look for files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting

```
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
```

when I try to call

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

from my boot.rb

the reason is that ruby does not have an idea about the bundler libs location which is

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler
```

how can I add this path to ruby? is it via appending the $Path? if yes is it good practice to append the libs for each gem to the path since each gem has its own local lib structure!

PS
I added $GEM_HOME to my env variables which is pointing to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and it didnt solve the issue

BTW Does ruby understand $GEM_HOME env variable? if yes does it dig deep into its directories?

Comment: `ruby -e "puts Gem.path"` prints where Ruby looks for gems. Also look at `gem env` and `gem which bundler`.

Comment: nice! so when I say for example    require 'bundler';     ruby will execute gem which bundler and search in the path

Comment: It turns out to be a little more complicated than that (ruby doesn't literally execute `gem`). In some versions of Ruby on some OSes, gem and ruby can disagree about what the paths are, leading to confusion. You sometimes end up adding paths to GEM_HOME. See my possibly relevant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945228/i-see-gem-in-gem-list-but-have-no-such-file-to-load/2945509#2945509. I don't know if that's part of the problem you're having or not.

Answer (score -1):

what if you add bundler gem to your Gemfile?

Comment: the same error. FYI if I run bundle exec rails .... it works! may be it is dependency issue.

Comment: Adding bundler to your Gemfile doesn't make sense. Bundler is what reads your Gemfile in the first place.