# Rakefile Albacore on a Mac

Tags: ruby, mono, rake

Ive been using a RakeFile on my PC for a long time. Just switched over to Mac. I want to execute some mono exe files with the same rake file, but it won't even run on the mac.
I ran `gem install albacore` but it doesnt seem to have worked correctly. Please advise.

I get this error when i try to run it:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- albacore
```

Here is the beginning of my rake file:

```
require 'albacore'
require 'rubygems'
require 'ftools'
....
    class Exec
  include RunCommand
  include YAMLConfig
  include Logging

  def initialize
    @path_to_command=''
    @parameters = []
    super()
  end

  def execute
    result = run_command "Exec", ""

    failure_message = 'Exec Failed. See Build Log For Detail'
    fail_with_message failure_message if !result
  end
end
```

**UPDATE: Various Console output**

```
Chris@mbp 
$ sudo gem install albacore
Password:
Successfully installed albacore-0.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for albacore-0.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for albacore-0.3.5...

Chris@mbp
$ rake database:Sandbox
(in /Users/Chris/projects/DFT)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- albacore
/Users/Chris/projects/DFT/rakefile:1:in `require'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Chris@mbp
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

albacore (0.3.5)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
```

Comment: When you say the gem install didn't seem to have worked correctly, did you get any error messages? If you do `gem list`, do you see albacore? Are you using any ruby version managers like rvm, rbenv, or chruby? Are you using bundler? What command are you using when you are trying to run your rake file and get the `rake aborted` error?

Comment: @carolclarinet I have updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your GEM_HOME vs your LOAD_PATH. There are several ways of diagnosing and fixing the exact problem [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945228/i-see-gem-in-gem-list-but-have-no-such-file-to-load).